# SSL Curl POST of JSON data from Google App Engine for PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, mailchimp

I'm trying to use the MailChimp API (Version 2) to add an email subscriber to a List. I'm using the Google App Engine with Version 5.5 of PHP.

The response the API Server is supposed to give me should look something like below:

```
{
    "email": "example email",
    "euid": "example euid",
    "leid": "example leid"
}
```

However, I don't get any response or error message from the server. I do get `false` when I use `var_dump`.

Here is my code:

```
$api_url_str = "https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe";
$api_data_str = '{
"apikey": "'.$my_api_key.'",
"id": "'.$my_list_id.'",
"email": {"email": "'.$my_email_addr.'"},
"double_optin": false,
"merge_vars":
{
    "FNAME": "'.$my_first_name.'",
    "LNAME": "'.$my_last_name.'",
    "OPTIN_IP": "'.$my_ip_address.'",
    "OPTIN_TIME": "2015-05-22 10:22:09"
}
}';

$ch = curl_init($api_url_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_data_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($api_data_str)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$api_response_str = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The above code works (as expected) when I run it on my local PC (also PHP 5.5).

Anyone have this issue?

Comment: *What* issue? You didn't say what goes wrong.

Comment: I said it's not working on Google App Engine but it's working on local PC?!

Comment: But "not working" is not useful. What happens? What doesn't happen that you expected to happen? What errors do you see?

Comment: I've edited the question. It should be clearer now.

Comment: Sound like a bug. Please file an issue at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?q=Language=PHP

Answer (score 0):

After trying a couple of things, I stumbled on the following solution that works ([I got the relevant code from here](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/blob/master/src/Drewm/MailChimp.php)).

Here's the full code:

```
$api_url_str = "https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe";
$api_data_str = '{
"apikey": "'.$my_api_key.'",
"id": "'.$my_list_id.'",
"email": {"email": "'.$my_email_addr.'"},
"double_optin": false,
"merge_vars":
{
    "FNAME": "'.$my_first_name.'",
    "LNAME": "'.$my_last_name.'",
    "OPTIN_IP": "'.$my_ip_address.'",
    "OPTIN_TIME": "2015-05-22 10:22:09"
}
}';
$json_data = $api_data_str;
$context = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent'       => 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0',
        'method'           => 'POST',
        'header'           => "Content-type: application/json\r\n".
            "Connection: close\r\n" .
            "Content-length: " . strlen($json_data) . "\r\n",
        'content' => $json_data
        )
    );
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$api_response_str = file_get_contents($api_url_str, false, $context);
```

I'm not sure if it's prone to the breakage I've just recently experienced with CURL on Google PHP App Engine though, but for now it will have to do. I had a test script that I used to test Mandrill mail sends that worked with App Engine about a month ago, but it doesn't anymore, probably the same issue with CURL.

I hope this helps someone with the same challenge.